# Turn on LED for notification on Android M

Tags: android

I am working on a LED testing app for notification. I want to turn on/blink LED when notification received. My Android device show's notification on my screen but I don't see the led being on/ blink.

following is my code for notification in onCreate Method

```
Notification notf = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(0xff0000, 5000, 100)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText("Test")
            .setContentTitle("Akshay")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .build();

    notf.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(2, notf);
```

Do I need to add any permission top my Manifest file or implement any Android Class to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

`setLights()` is a request, not a command. It is up to the device manufacturer — or whoever created the version of Android running on the device — whether to use an LED for notifications or not. The device may also vary its approach based on other factors (e.g., use the LED to show charging status, and only use it for notifications if the device is not being charged).

Comment: Manufacturer has dedicated these LED's are for Notification purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html explains that 
for FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS

> Since hardware varies, you are not guaranteed that any of the values
>   you pass are honored exactly. Use the system defaults if possible
>   because they will be set to values that work on any given hardware.

int FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS

Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if you want the LED on for this notification.

To turn the LED off, pass 0 in the alpha channel for colorARGB or 0 for both ledOnMS and ledOffMS.
To turn the LED on, pass 1 for ledOnMS and 0 for ledOffMS.
To flash the LED, pass the number of milliseconds that it should be on and off to ledOnMS and ledOffMS.